# Too many requests made by this IP. Key reason?

Tags: support, api

This is may seem as a duplicate but I want to get this straight. I am sending some requests to the Stack Exchange API for a project I am running. But after testing it I get this response:

```
{'error_id': 502, 'error_message': 'too many requests from this IP, more 
requests available in 80281 seconds', 'error_name': 'throttle_violation'}
```

So I have a couple of questions:

1. I signed up for a key and the Stack Exchange API gave me a key but I am not using it anywhere. If I am making queries that do not include my key, why am I getting one? Or I am supposed to use it and I don't?
2. Is there a way I can override this? Or I just have to wait?

Comment: Take a look at http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: you should add in each call you make to the API the query parameter `&key=your-key-found-at-the-app-page`

Answer (score 2):

> 1) I signed up for a key and the StackExchage API gave me a key but I am not using it anywhere. If I am making queries that do not include my key, why am I getting one? Or I am supposed to use it and I don't?

You should use the key; if you don't, you're limited to 300 requests a day. The key will give you up to [10,000](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

> 2) Is there a way I can override this? Or I just have to wait?

Each JSON response from the API contains a `quota_remaining` field (unless you disabled it in the filter) which tells you how many requests you have left, and sometimes a `backoff` parameter telling you not to send requests for the next *n* seconds. If you respect those, you should not see these kind of error messages..